# UIImage with CGAffineTransform drawn in CGContext strange output

Tags: uiimageview, uikit, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform

I have a UIView containing a UIImageView, I apply a rotation transform to the UIImageView and then want to draw that image with same rotation transform in a CGContext (and in future more transforms like translation and scale will be used), I have following code to make the transformation and drawing in CGContext:

```
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"cena-1.png"];
CGRect imageFrame=CGRectMake(50, 50, image.size.width, image.size.height);
UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
imageView.image=image;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

CGAffineTransform imageTransform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(10));
imageView.transform=imageTransform;
NSLog(@"self.imgOverlay.image.scale: %f", imageView.image.scale);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

CGContextConcatCTM(context, imageView.transform);

CGRect modifiedRect=CGRectApplyAffineTransform(imageFrame, imageTransform);
[imageView.image drawInRect:modifiedRect];

UIGraphicsPopContext();
UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSString *jpgPath=[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.jpg"];
NSData *imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(outputImage, 1.0);
[imageData writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];

NSLog(@"putputImage path: %@", jpgPath);
```

.

The problem is the outputimage doesn't look same as it is shown in UIKit's UIVIew, it gets skewed and position is not accurate as well, here is a screenshot:

[image]

Please guide me on what I am doing wrong, thanks for your help :)

p.s. I have also posted another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873202/uiimage-drawn-in-cgcontext-with-cgaffinetransform-unexpected-results) with explaining the complete scenario however answer to this question will hopefully be enough.

**UPDATE**
I have tried `[imageView.image drawAtPoint:modifiedRect.origin];` it corrects the skew problem (http://screencast.com/t/v2oKkmkd) but the position issue remains :(

**UPDATE 2**
Here is a test project with a little modified code: https://github.com/abduliam/TestTransform

Comment: Try using PNG representation... Sometimes the JPEG function inexplicably doesn't work but the PNG function does.

Comment: @DylanKirkby Thanks for your comment, tried it (http://screencast.com/t/0mgge4LEHRF) no luck, the situation is more complex, I think it has something to do with the difference in coordinate system of CG and UIKit :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than rotating the rect, rotate the entire drawing context and then draw it in that rect.

For example, this will draw the image rotated -15 degrees:

```
    CGRect clipped = CGRectInset(screenRect, 100, 100);
    CGContextRotateCTM(ctx,  -15 * M_PI / 180.0);
    [imageView.image drawInRect: clipped];
```

Comment: thanks for taking time and answering my question :) I did managed to solve the problem, don't exactly remember what was the solution, however it can be seen in action on the appstore: https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/cena-me-photobooth/id645765826